# iOS Panorama UI

Tags: ios, opencv, panoramas

I am trying to create a Panorama app for iPhone/iPad.

The image stitching bit is OK, I'm using openCV libraries and the results are pretty acceptable.

But I'm a bit stuck on developing the UI for assisting the user while capturing the panorama.

Most apps (even on Android) would provide user with some sort of a marker that translates/rotates exactly matching the movement of the user's camera.
[I'm using the iOS 7 - default camera's panorama feature as a preliminary benchmark].

However, I'm way off the mark till date.

**What I've tried:** 
I've tried using the accelerometer and gyro data for tracking the marker. With this approach -

- I've applied an LPF on the accelerometer data and used simple
  Newtonian mechanics (with a carefully tuned damping factor) to
  translate the marker on the screen. *Problem with this approach:* very erratic data. Marker tends to jump and wobble between points. Hard to tell between smooth movement and jerk.
- I've tried using a complimentary filter between LPF-ed gyro and
  accelerometer data to translate the blob. *Problem with this approach:* Slightly better than the first approach, but still quite random.
- I've also tried using image processing to compute optical flow. I'm
  using openCV's

  ```
  goodFeaturesToTrack(firstMat, cornersA, 30, 0.01, 30);
  ```

  to get the trackable points from a first image (sampled from camera
  picker) and then using `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`  to get the positions
  of these points in the next image.
  *Problem with this approach:* However, the motions vectors obtained from tracking these points are too noisy to compute the resultant
  direction of motion accurately.

**What I think I should do next:**

- Perhaps compute the DCT matrix from accelerometer and gyro data and
  use some algorithm to filter one output with the other.
- Work on the image processing algorithms, use some different techniques
  (???).
- Use Kalman filter to fuse the state prediction from
  accelerometer+gyro with that of the image processing block.

**The help that I need:**

Can you suggest some easier way to get this job done?

If not, can you highlight any possible mistake in my approach? Does it really have to be this complicated?

Please help.